# Is there a maximum number of formula fields allowed in Excel (2010)

Tags: excel, limit, formula

Im using a csv file to build some insert statements for SQL server and am trying to clean my data before it gets inserted, and am using formulas to fo it. I have around 64000 rows and about 30 columns to clean.

Ive got most of the way through it, but now a formula to make sure telephone numbers are correct has just started to fail, and now just puts the text of the forumla into the cell, rather than the cleaned telephone number. The same forumla is working in other cells.

Is there a limit to the number of formula you can have in a workbook or worksheet?

I am using Excel 2010

Comment: No such limit on total number of formulas exists, your problem must lie elsewhere.  (FWIW I just ran a simple test with 64000*300 formula with no problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010073849.aspx for limits on specs  it doesn't indicate a set formula limit but you may be hitting one of the other ones.

For example: Unique cell formats/cell styles    64,000

Answer (score 2):

The answer may be frustrating: it depends.   You may be running out of RAM, or hitting other limits, depending on how many other Worksheets are open, etc.   On my laptop, I get the same effect of limits to the number of formula, but it takes more formula to generate it than you indicate.   A Worksheet with more than about10^6 to 10^8 formulas starts to hang.   The same Worksheet works fine on my desktop.   It may depend on the type of formula, that is, 10^8 VLOOKUPS will hang but 10^8 SUM statements are ok.  It may depend on how the formulas are laid out on the Worksheet (if all in a small number of adjacent columns (such as 100 x 10^6), it will be faster and hang less than if spreadout in a square matrix of 10^4 x 10^4).

Answer (score 0):

This is generally an issue with the formatting of the cell before you put the formula in.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula may be entered as text. Try:
1. Home | Editing | Clear | Clear Formats.
2. Reenter your formula (F2 Enter).