# Number of formula exceeded (MS Excel 2007)

Tags: excel, matrix, limit, formula, vba

I've already searched for solution and found only this related topic ([Is there a maximum number of formula fields allowed in Excel (2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702970/is-there-a-maximum-number-of-formula-fields-allowed-in-excel-2010)) which didn't bring me any answer.

I'm working in MS Excel 2007. I have a square matrix of 6250*6250 cells. Each cell should contain this kind of formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF($D8=F$6;SLOOKUP($D8;INDIRECT($B$1);3;FALSE);SLOOKUP($D8&"x"&F$6;INDIRECT($B$2);4;FALSE));0)
```

(don't check the formula itself, since I only quickly translated the names of the functions from my native language to English)

Well, if I copy the formula through the whole square matrix I get an error saying:

> Excel cannot complete this task with available resources. Choose less
>   or close other applications.

Any suggestions how to solve or bypass this problem? I need the output to be a square matrix.

Running on Intel i7 4770, 8 GB DDR3, Win10 64.

Comment: If you are open to a VBA solution that can do what your formula does and dumps the results in the range you specify, you may want to add the Excel-VBA tag to your question.  You may also find that it speed up your calculations!

Comment: I am open to any solution. Can you please explain or direct me to a source where I could learn how to use VBA? Thanks for the reply

Comment: I started to learn VBA by reading examples and asking questions.  I would find my example by doing google searches of "Excel VBA how write a formula to a cell" or Excel VBA how to loop through cells", etc.  It takes time.  I would re ask your question and post it in the Excel-VBA tag.  And you want to ask for assistance in converting your above formula to VBA code so you can avoid the INDIRECT statement.  I would also try and get some basic VBA code written so you can show them you are trying.  A good question shows research, what the problem is, what the question is, and what you have tried.

Comment: you may even want to link your new question to this question.  And the reason you want to show what you have tried, is that it frustrates a lot of people on here when they ask question and show no effort at all.  As long as you show effort and a willingness to learn, there are lots of people on here that will want to help you out.  Unfortunately VBA is not my area of expertise.  I can read it, but I cannot write it.  A good way to start to learn VBA is to record a macro of what you are doing.  The macro is equal VBA code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply again. I will do as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

[MS Excel 2007 Limitation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-16c69c74-3d6a-4aaf-ba35-e6eb276e8eaa) are listed in that link.  Scroll down to the calculation specifications and you may see some numbers that pop out at you that give you an idea where the issue is.

Aside from that you could try copying your formula into your square matrix one column or row at a time and see which point you get the error.  if you get it on the first paste its probably not an error with the number of formulas.

On an aside, I noticed you are using `indirect` which is a volatile function.  This means each volatile function is recalculated anytime anything is entered on the worksheet.  Over the number of cells you are looking at, it could bog your system down.  You MAY want to consider a VBA option.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are correct. It took about 4 mins to calculate with A LOT smaller matrix.
I will look into the VBA solution.